# How to create new shipping module with user input during checkout?

Tags: module, shipping, custom, user

I bought a couple of books on Magento extension development and understood the mechanism on how to create a new shipping module. However in my current project I need to allow the customer to enter his/her own shipping account number and the number should appear in the order details (similar to a tracking number).

In other words, during checkout the customer should see:
Shipping Method
  Customer Shipping Account
  Carrier [dropdown list to choose UPS, FedEx and Others]
  Account Number [free text]

Where should I start looking for documentation on how this can be implemented? Sorry I am very new to magento development.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good point of reference:

[Magento Checkout Page – Add Custom Fields](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page)

You may also want to consider the pro's and con's of developing this yourself vs. purchasing a paid for extension which already has the foundation laid for the functionality you seek.

But it is definitely do-able, and worth the challenge which will be very rewarding once completed. Just note though that you will need to maintain the functionality going forwards, perhaps even over multiple versions of Magento.

GL!

Comment: I found the following article which helps a lot in understanding the different areas that need to be customized: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-shipping-method-development